# SharePoint Web Services, Access Denied, Authentication Issues via VS 2010

Tags: web-services, authentication, iis-7, sharepoint-2007

After not getting much help on the last question, I decided to blow away the VM and re-create it as I already lost a week on this issue. And of course still issues, btu a little different.

I am using WSS on a 2008 server. I removed from the SharePoint admin the blocked asmx page types. I am using the administrator account with password and the domain, which is the IP of the VM machine. Normally I would never recommend using the admin account, but since I am just running a test to connect to SharePoint web services, so be it.

When accessing this site via a webbrowser, no issues whatsoever.

[image]

When accessing the web services from the browser using the admin credentials, no problem.

[image]

Then when trying to access the web service via Visual Studio I get the windows security dialog;

[image]

Followed by a discovery credential for the list;

[image]

Followed by another Discovery Credential for access to the error.aspx page, but as you can see, I can see the list of services for lists.asmx;

[image]

Followed by yet another Discovery Credential asking for permission to the $metadata and this just continues continually -it will NEVER authenticate via visual studio 2010;

[image]

And then, of course, when the code is ran, what do we get - ACCESS DENIED.

Call made; code not listed makes connection.

Make call to service:

[image]

And receive the error.

[image]

[image]

And IIS for SharePoint is set top Windows Authentication and Impersonate. All defaults.

[image]

It has now been going on 5 days; does anyone at all have any clue as to what is causing this? I have used this code and technique for years with Windows Server 2003 and WSS 2.0 and / or MOSS 2007 connecting from remote machines and NEVER, I mean NEVER had issues like this.

I would really appreciate any help.